# 404 error for any action with asp.net core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net5

With a brand new project created from scratch (not a visual studio template), using Kestrel as server, and a very simple Startup.cs that just initializes MVC with `services.AddMvc();` and `app.UseMvc();`, any request to a controller action returns a 404 error instead of running the action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out there was a typo in my `project.json`.

This compiles but does not work: `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.MVC": "1.0.0-rc2-final",`

This works fine: `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",`

Don't see the difference? Took me quite a while to find it. The version that does not work is using uppercase `MVC`, while the correct version is `Mvc`. Why it compiles but silently fails at runtime is a mystery for me though.